# angular js - HTML returned from a service function in a ng-repeat renders as text

Tags: angularjs

When I call a function, that provides a block of HTML, from within an ng-repeat, it is rendering as text, but I would like this to render the HTML. How should I approach this? :

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in data.people">
   <td class="text-left">
       {{getInitials(person.Firstname, person.Surname, person.IconColor )}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

I have a function in a service which returns a block of HTML:

```
angular.module('myapp.services.global', [])
.factory('helperFunctions', function () {
    return {
        getInitials: function (firstname, lastname, iconColor) {
            return "<div style='background-color:" + iconColor + "' class='userIconMedium'>" + firstname.charAt(0) + " " + lastname.charAt(0) + "</div>";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect place to use a directives.

Comment: I'm keen to dive into custom directives, but am finding it a little tricky to get started with. Any examples as to how this simple example could be moved into a directive would be really useful.

Comment: Sure I understand. I posted an answer including a directive definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned that this is a perfect place for a directive however I realize that directives can be difficult to understand at first glance. Directives are used to link in with the DOM. Rendering HTML within Angular should usually be limited to directives.

You would modify your HTML to have the directive.

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in data.people">
    <td class="text-left">
       <div myapp-initials="person" ></div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Your angular module would no longer contain a factory definition but a directive definition.

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
.directive('myappInitials', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "<div style='background-color:{{myappInitials.IconColor}}' class='userIconMedium'>{{myappInitials.Firstname.charAt(0) + ' ' + myappInitials.Surname.charAt(0)}}</div>",
    scope: {
      myappInitials: "="
    }
  };
});
```

I have [created a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h7f3z2kZpUEvIMEX7zOg?p=preview) to demonstrate how to use a directive in your situation.

Comment: Please include some code from example to your answer because your answer won't mean anything if plunker disappears.

Comment: Hi @Joel - Thanks for your example. This works fine except it doesn't render the inline style on IE9. It renders '{{myappInitials.IconColor}' into the HTML. This works fine on Chrome but not on IE9. It is the same on your Plunker. Is this an Angular bug that needs reporting? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Further to this, the above accepted answer is not quite correct. IE (including 11) does not support interpolation in style attributes. You must use ngStyle for that, e.g
ng-style="{'background-color': myAppInitials.IconColor}"

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

This is my working solution based on the directive kindly provided by @Joel above, though I'd prefer to include the ng-style element within the template of the directive but I am not yet sure whether this is possible:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in data.people">
    <td class="text-left">
       <div ng-style="{'background-color':person.IconColor}" class="userIconMedium" myapp-initials="person"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
    .directive('myappInitials', function () {
       return {
          restrict: 'A',
          template: "{{myappInitials.Firstname.charAt(0) + ' ' + myappInitials.Surname.charAt(0)}}",
          scope: {
             myappInitials: "="
          }
};
 });
```